# Getting name for a WPF shape from variable

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to initialize and show a ellipse (WPF shape) in a function.The name of the ellipse should be given to the function as a parameter.

Is there a possibility to do something like that ?

Edit:

The following is given:

```
private void A1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Feld A1 gedrückt";            
        //Spielstein setzen
        //Rêgeln überprüfen
        myEllipse = new Ellipse();
        myEllipse.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        myEllipse.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        myEllipse.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        myEllipse.Margin = new Thickness(2, 2, 0, 0);
        myEllipse.Width = 45;
        myEllipse.Height = 45;
        grid3.Children.Add(myEllipse);
        A1.IsHitTestVisible = false;

    }
```

What I want to do is to get the name("myEllipse") from a string variable. For example:

```
string name = 'myEllipse';
name = newEllipse();
myEllipse.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
```

Comment: Dude, please elaborate. Post your XAML or something. Also, in WPF you don't manipulate UI elements in code (usually), so please explain what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: Check the edited text in my first post.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but if you're talking about the `Name="SomeName"` that is usually found in the XAML, I think that name is for the compiler only, but not necessarily a value of a field or property of the object. I could be wrong, though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it from your code you are you trying to create multiple instances of Ellipse which you can then recall and modify when needed? If so, one way to do this is to create a List or Dictionary and add the ellipses you create to them, which you can then recall when needed through the index (if it's a list) or key (if it's a dictionary).

```
List<Ellipse> myEllipses = new List<Ellipse>();

Private void A1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myEllipse = new Ellipse();
    myEllipses.Add(myEllipse);
    ...
}
```